# Using TaskFactory.StartNew inside loop: state object doesn't work

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

First of all I initialize searchContext list:

```
var searchContexts = new List<SearchContext>();

for (byte pageNumber = 1; pageNumber < 6; pageNumber++)
{
    var searchContext = GetSearchContext(context, vendor, workRequest, pageNumber);

    searchContexts.Add(searchContext);
}
```

where SearchContext is defined as follows:

```
public class SamoSearchContext
{
    public WorkRequest WorkRequest 
    { get; set; }

    public Vendor Vendor 
    { get; set; }

    public WorkResponse WorkResponse
    { get; set; }

    public byte PageNumber 
    { get; set; }
}
```

Then for each searchContext start new thread:

```
var tasks = new Task[taskCount];         
var taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.Default;

var index = 0;
foreach (var searchContext in searchContexts)
{

    var ssc = searchContext;

    tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew((obj) => SendSearchRequest(ssc, token),
                ssc, token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, taskScheduler);

    index++;
 }
```

SendSearchRequest() method call outside service to get the next search result page (by pageNumber). Here is the implementation:

```
 private void SendSearchRequest(SamoSearchContext context, CancellationToken token)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        var workRequest = context.WorkRequest;

        workRequest.@params.PRICE_PAGE = context.PageNumber;

        context.WorkResponse = ServiceClient.GetWorkResponse<WorkRequest, WorkResponse>(ServiceOperations.GetPrice, workRequest, context.Vendor.UniformCode, context.Vendor.ID);
```

}

But reading logs after the loop execution I see that pageNumber is always = 4.

Could not understand what's wrong?

Comment: `pageNumber`, where/how is it used?

Comment: You prevented closing over the loop issue for `searchContext` but forgot about `index`. Is that the problem you're talking about?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel But `index` is not used inside the lambda, so I don't see how could that be the issue.

Comment: @svick You're right. I misread `token` as `index`.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, I initialize searchContext list with the same search request(workRequest), the same vendor, the same additional context, just pageNumber is different. Than, concurrently, invoke outside search service, which retrieve results page by page by search request (workRequest) and pageNumber. But it seems I'm doing something wrong, because pageNumber is always = 4 (the next to the last value). Could not understand why it is captured each time.

Comment: I've added SendSearchRequst implementation for more completeness

Comment: I guess you're saying that your "context.PageNumber" is always coming 4. If that is the case then, can you try replacing the **ssc** with **obj** in the line `Task.Factory.StartNew((obj) => SendSearchRequest(**ssc**, token),`. See if that's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The matter is when I create SearchContext list, I indiscreetly used copy workRequest by reference (newSearchContext.WorkRequest = workRequest). So all SearchContexts in the list reference to the one workRequest instance. Then, in SendRequest() each time I've changed PRICE_PAGE field of this one instance. So it was the same, a bit strange that it always = 4, but not a random number from 1 to 5.

But, nevertheless, now I implement Clone() extension method for WorkRequest which copy the object field by field into a new instance. Now it works. Thanks everybody for participation!